# Backend Azure com C#. Criar um novo campo em uma tabela

Tags: microsoft-azure, cloud

Tenho um backend construído em C#, com o Microsoft Azure e banco de dados SQL Server.

Para que eu adicione um novo campo em uma tabela, o que devo fazer?

Seria somente ir no designer dessa tabela, via visual studio, adicionar o que desejo e clicar em update?

Meu configuration:

```
public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            ContextKey = "appService.Models.appContext";
            SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
        }
```

Comment: Depende da sua estratégia de deploy. O jeito que citou, abrindo VS, é o mais manual possível. Se for projeto pequeno e baixa atualização, sem problema. Mas sempre se pode aprimorar indo para automações.

Comment: Sempre que tento utilizar o Add-Migrations ele da problema, por isso minha pergunta. A atualização e criação das tabelas é pequena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende da sua estratégia de deploy.

Fazer atualização manual, como usando o Visual Studio, ou um SQL Management, é totalmente possível.

Porém, o ideal é sempre tentar criar automações para isso, seja usando skill de desenvolvedores, como Migrations e CakeBuild, ou skill DevOps com Visual Studio Team System, Octopus, etc.